# scanner input loop until enter or keypress

Tags: java, eclipse, input, java.util.scanner

I am creating a java program that asks the user for 2 inputs, the first input will be the numerator and the second input will be denominator. for example if i write 10 5 (user press enter), then the answer will be 2 since 10/5 = 2.

I also want to be able to write several inputs for example: 10 5 20 4 30 5  (user press enter)
then answer will be 2, 5, 6.
If i write 10 5 20 (user press enter)
then the answer is only 2 and the third input is disgarded.

here's my code:

```
public class test {

   private static Scanner userpress = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int choice = 1;
      int r;
      int h;

      System.out.println("---------------------------------");
      System.out.println("write your two numbers (numerator, denominator)");

      while (userpress.hasNextInt()) {
         userpress.useDelimiter("\\s");
         r = userpress.nextInt();
         h = userpress.nextInt();
         userpress.nextLine();
         int x = r / h;
         System.out.println(x);
      }
        System.out.println("user dont want play more!")

   }

}
```

When i write 10 5 20 5
i get the output 2. but i want to get the output 2, 4. If i write 10 5 20 5 30 6, i want to get output 2, 4, 5. How can I do this? if the user writes 10 5 20 5 e, then i want the output to be 2, 4, user dont want play more!

Comment: read as string then split ... ?

Comment: can you show me what you mean in code

Comment: Just remove this `userpress.nextLine();`

Comment: when i removed `user.press.nextLine();` it worked, i can have several inputs, but when the inputs are uneven for example, 10 5 20, i get inputmismatchexception. how can i make it disregard the last input if its uneven.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

- 1. just get the delimiter before the while loop.
- 2. remove the nextLine().
- 3. If you need another improvement, let us know (Like exit the program).

```
        userpress.useDelimiter("\\s"); // here
        while (userpress.hasNextInt()) {
            // userpress.useDelimiter("\\s"); // remove
            if(userpress.hasNextInt()) // for uneven values
                r = userpress.nextInt();
            if(userpress.hasNextInt()) // for uneven values
                h = userpress.nextInt();
            //userpress.nextLine(); // remove 
            int x = r / h;
            System.out.println(x);

            // for "e" 
            if( !userpress.hasNextInt() && userpress.hasNextLine()) { // if input is not integer and exists
                message();
                /*String e =*/ userpress.nextLine(); // clean the cache
            }
        }
```

Comment: but when the inputs are uneven for example, 10 5 20, i get inputmismatchexception. how can i make it disregard the last input if its uneven

Comment: I also want to check that if the string e is inputed by the user for example 10 5 e, then the program should return the answer for 10/5 and call another method.

Comment: maybe creating a string array by the size of the amount of inputs the user presses and then loop through all the inputs?

Comment: Then you need to use nextLine(), because nextInt will crash if you insert a string.
Let's work on it.

Comment: We must go step by step. 1st we address uneven issue.

Comment: uneven values is ok. The other case of "e" is tricky. Could you explain more

Comment: i have another method called `public static void message(){ System.out.println("you pressed e");}` I want it to be called if the user for example writes: 10 5 20 4 e, then the outcome should be `2, 5, you pressed e`

Comment: In the answer code I must initialize `r` and `h` otherwise i get error.

Comment: Inserti this `System.out.println(x);` after `if( !userpress.hasNextInt() && userpress.hasNextLine()) {
                message();
                e = userpress.nextLine();
            }`

Comment: I don't understand it, can you please show it in code the whole answer. why `e = userpress.nextLine();` what does that do?

Comment: it s to clear the cache. Comment it and test

Comment: `e` is not a variable, so i must declare it first to a string. and if i do, the if statement is run all the time regardless if i input e or not.

Comment: Sorry! declare or avoid it